Don't show deleted answers in "Other answers" in the Late answers review queue
I frequently look at the other answers when reviewing the Late answers queue to search for duplicates, but showing deleted answers here just wastes my time. On a recent case I clicked on "Other answer (1)" just to see that the other answer has been deleted 10 months ago:

Is there some case in which the deleted answers would influence the review of some late answer? If not, can we hide them?

"Is there some case in which the deleted answers would influence the review of some late answer?" I don't believe anybody can categorically rule it out. What if the late answer is the third time the user has reposted the same thing and the other two are deleted? What if this was indeed the user's first answer yet they post the same link as in an answer nuked as spam? What if there are just a bunch of deleted answers as link only already and there is a new one - not spam but might merit at least a protection, if not closure?

"Is there some case in which the deleted answers would influence the review of some late answer?" Yes... For example, someone reposting an answer that had already been removed by a moderator.

@CodyGray in that case shouldn’t the new answer have the same issues as the deleted one, and so fail the review on its own?

@bfontaine would you intuitively know why a particular answer was deleted by a mod? When you don't even see the answer was deleted?

Ok so show answers deleted by a mod, but hide those deleted by its author.

I see - so you asked for why you'd want to see deleted answers. But when presented with evidence, you just immediately changed to make that an exemption. So, the query wasn't genuine, you seem dead set on your request being correct and begrudgingly accept specific exemptions.

@VLAZ Please assume good faith and avoid personal attacks. The query is genuine and I’m refining it based on feedback: so far, all the examples showed that mod-deleted answers are useful, but not author-deleted ones, like the example I included in the answer.

You were presented with multiple examples. You completely ignored mine. You tried to argue Cody's doesn't matter. When finally shown your argument against Cody's was weak. Instead of accepting that, you've been shown a reason to leave deleted answers, you shifted the goal posts. This is not an attack, I've listed the actions I observed from you. I don't see where you've shown good faith in trying to accept examples that go against your proposal.

@bfontaine "but not author-deleted ones" here's yet another example, lets say an author posts an answer, it gets downvoted due to whatever reason, they self delete and repost to bypass the downvotes. No moderator deletion involved here, would you consider being able to see the deleted answers useful in this case? Personally I'd say just consider it a curse of seeing deleted posts due to having 10k+ rep and live with it.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks, that’s a good point.

@VLAZ I wasn’t sure because it doesn’t seem you can mention multiple usernames in one comment, so I didn’t mention you and assumed you would receive a notification anyway, because my response addressed your comment as well. Sorry if I doesn’t understand you well, but I read your comment as if when I criticize some of your/Cody’s points it’s bad faith, but when you criticize mine it’s normal and I shouldn’t try to respond. For me that’s just how a debate works, and Abdul Aziz Barkat closed it: both mod-deleted and author-deleted answers can be useful.

I don't see how "shouldn’t the new answer have the same issues as the deleted one, and so fail the review on its own?" covers protecting the question. Yes, the new answer will have the same problem - it shouldn't have been posted in that case. And there would be an extra step from failing the review. Yes, protection is not part of the review actions but to me seems sensible to still do it.

And nor does your initial comment even fully address the first scenario I painted - three answers by the same user, two deleted. That includes deletion by mods, by other users, or self-deletions. In that situation, simply "failing the review" (meaning what, suggest deletion? So they can post yet again?)  is not enough and most likely calls for a modflag (also a possible review action but did you really mean you'd do that?)

@VLAZ Got it, I forgot that sometimes it goes beyond the individual answer and so seeing the deleted answers is helpful to see the global situation. Sorry if it took me half a dozen comments to realize it.

It is impossible to categorically rule out that a deleted answer will be useful for a review.
Therefore, I believe this feature request should not be implemented.
